# Disabling AutoLayout for a single View Controller in storyBoard

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a  specific scene(view controller) in storyboard for which i do not want autoLayout. Disabling Autolayout in storyboard disables it for the entire storyboard for all scenes. 
For now I am having that view controller as a separate .xib and disabling autoLayout for it. Is this the correct way of doing it or is there another option available to disable autoLayout for a particular view controller in storyboard?

Note: I have a compass implemented in this view controller. The compass is jerky when autoLayout is enabled. That is the reason i do not want to use autoLayout for this view controller.

Comment: You can remove the auto layout for the one view in xib. Bt you can't do that in storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the single view for that view controller into its own XIB file is a perfectly reasonable way to achieve this.